# C# - Ordering a list by the initial letters of its elements (StartsWith)

Tags: c#, string, list, startswith

Consider a standard list.
I need my list to be sorted in a manner that the first elements to be shown are the ones that StartsWith("SI_IS")

I asked one of my friends and he told me to use a lambda custom function, is this true?

The output should be something like

```
SI_ISFieldName
SI_ISbFieldName
SI_IScFieldName
F_FieldName
TB_FieldName
TB_bFieldName
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional `OrderBy`, just remember that `true` is higher than `false`:

```
var q = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.StartsWith("SI_IS"));
```

or maybe you find this more readable:

```
var q = items.OrderBy(s => s.StartsWith("SI_IS") ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: Probably followed by a `.ThenBy()`

Comment: @RandRandom: `ThenBy(what)`? OP's desired result is not ordered. It's just split into two groups and the `SI_IS`-group begins. This approach uses a stable sort, so the ordering remains same in both groups. But you're right, if he wants to order them he needs to append `ThenBy`.

Comment: Rango, you for sure edited your comment alot - for my little remark. :) - Basically, I just wanted to drop the comment for OP to see that his ordering could be extended with `ThenBy`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use OrderBy with Lambda expression

```
myList.OrderByDescending(t => t.StartsWith("SI_IS"));
```

where `t.StartsWith("SI_IS")` is the custom function part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq for this like

```
listElements.OrderBy(x => x.StartsWith("SI_IS")).ToList();
```